# How to split ng-repeat into batches

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am doing this ref:checkbox example at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-examples

```
<div class="btn-group list-group-item-text" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label data-ng-repeat="type in types"
         ng-class="{btn: true, 'btn-primary': true, active: Map[type.id]}">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Map[type.id]">{{type.name}}
  </label>
</div>
```

Now the problem is sometimes this types array has less than 5 items sometimes more. The button group splits in an ugly way onto the next line when it has more than 5 items.

How can I do something like this

```
ng-repeat on 0-4 of array - create a button group for these 5 items
ng-repeat on 5-9 of array (if array length is >5) ...
ng-repeat on 10-14 of array (if array length is >10) ...
...
```

Note: What would be even better is to see how many characters have been used. Every type has different name, some long some short, so some times a really long name can use up all the width of the panel.

Answer (score 9):

With `ng-repeat` use two `limitTo` filters, with positive & negative values.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo

Heres a demo http://plnkr.co/edit/8LXXnH?p=preview

Updated example:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo: 5 | limitTo: -5">{{item}}</li>
<li ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo: 10 | limitTo: -5">{{item}}</li>
```

The first ng-repeat will return 0 to 4 of array, second ng-repeat will return 5 to 9.

Comment: Clever, but has a slight bug: it doesn't work as expected when the array is not divisible by the "limit size". In this case, if your `items` array had 9 items, item[4] would be displayed at the end of the first list, and at the beginning of the second list.

Comment: To get around that issue, my last batch uses the following logic: `item in items | limitTo:15 | limitTo:items.length % 5 * -1`, using modular division to determine how big the negative limit should be.

Answer (score 1):

You could pre-group them and then just use a nested repeater.

```
var groups = [],
    maxGroupSize = 4,
    groupNum = 0;

groups.push([]);
groupNum = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
  groups[groupNum].push(types[i]);

  if (groups[groupNum].length === maxGroupSize) {
      groups.push([]);
      groupNum++;
  }
}



$scope.groups = groups;
```

Then you can just use a nested repeater like so:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="group in groups"
   class="btn-group list-group-item-text" data-toggle="buttons">
     <label data-ng-repeat="type in group"
            ng-class="{btn: true, 'btn-primary': true, active: Map[type.id]}">
         <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Map[type.id]">{{type.name}}
     </label>
</div>
```

Here is an example jsFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/V8fuy/

**UPDATE:**

I've created an [updated version of the same fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/V8fuy/2/) to show using a little CSS to truncate the text with an elipsis. By adding a `title` attribute you can get default tooltip functionality, but it would be better to use the [Bootstrap Tooltip plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips).

You will probably need to create a directive or use something like [Angular Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

Comment: I would like to point out that in this solution, the grouping happens before the `$scope` assignment which is the right way to go. You wouldn't want to put scope variables inside a loop.

Comment: @AlexC: This also does not solve the problem: `Every type has different name, some long some short, so some times a really long name can use up all the width of the panel`. Just a simple css will do the trick, don't need to use grouping.

Comment: @KhanhTO oh sorry, I did not read the context carefully. Yeah css fixes are better.

Comment: @KhanhTO - Normally I would agree with you, but in this particular case, he is using a very specific Bootstrap construct, which is basically already doing the "CSS" trick you mention. The issue is that visually if it grows too wide, the group is broken. This could be mitigated by truncating the text with an ellipsis via CSS in order to keep it a specific width, and then adding a tooltip.

Comment: If we control `specific width`, we don't need grouping at all as it will automatically be wrapped to next line nicely because we can control both the line width and items' width. The problem is the names width vary. And what if the user resizes the window?

Comment: @KhanhTO - Look at the **specific** example using Twitter Bootstrap, not the plain jane Plunkr you provided. The inputs will already wrap down to the next line without any extra help with all text intact. You are trying to solve a problem he doesn't have. It's not an issue of the text wrapping, but the visual style of the button group being broken onto two lines.

Comment: @Josh: Sorry, did not notice that. But this also does not solve the problem anyway, especially when the user resizes the window

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but I guess you could just hardcode the limits with splice:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="group1Item in items.splice(limit1,limit2-limit1)"> ... </div>
<div data-ng-repeat="group2Item in items.splice(limit2,limit3-limit2)"> ... </div>
<div data-ng-repeat="group3Item in items.splice(limit3,limit4-limit3)"> ... </div>
```

This would be fine for relatively small arrays but I think pre-grouping is the way to go for larger arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a library, this is exactly what [lodash#chunk](https://lodash.com/docs#chunk) does.
Do the chunking in your controller and then write a nested for loop in your view.

> Creates an array of elements split into groups the length of size. If collection can’t be split evenly, the final chunk will be the remaining elements.

```
_.chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2);
// → [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]

_.chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 3);
// → [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d']]
```