# How do i return and display data 3 at a time? (Using Firebase and Angular)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, web, firebase

I've got a problem that I'm not sure how to solve using the "Angular way". I want to display returned data in rows of three. Basically I have a template that needs to be used like this:

```
<div class="row">
- data item 1
- data item 2
- data item 3
</div>

<div class="row">
- data item 4
- data item 5
- data item 6
</div>
```

My database (firebase) looks like this:

```
myUsers
------- 
{ name: "John", age: 33 }
{ name: "Ravi", age: 26 }
{ name: "Kate", age: 29 }
{ name: "Steve", age: 29 }
{ name: "Randall", age: 29 }
{ name: "Kevin", age: 32 }
```

And I fetch the users by using this code:

```
var myUsersUri = FIREBASE_URI + 'web/data/myUsers';
var ref = new Firebase(myUsersUri);
var query = ref.orderByChild("name");
var myUsers = $firebaseArray(query);
...
$scope.myUsers = myUsers;
```

This is where I'm stuck. The only thing I know how to do so far is display this data using ng-repeat, like this:

```
<div class="user" ng-repeat="(id, myUser) in myUsers">
{{ myUser.name }}
</div>
```

But I need it displayed in rows of three. Does anyone know how I would go about solving it.

I think the solution is to put the data into groups BEFORE I put it into $scope, so have a $scope.groups which is a collection of items split into rows.

Comment: Temporary solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424240/how-to-split-ng-repeat-into-batches

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28093529/5635057).
It's an easy solution that **does not require data manipulation** and you can just change one variable if you need more/less rows.

Here's the code adjusted to your situation:

The HTML:

```
<div class="label" ng-repeat="(id, myUser) in myUsers"
    ng-class="{'new-row': startNewRow($index, columnBreak) }">
    {{ myUser.name }}
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.label {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}
.new-row {
    clear: left;
}
```

The JavaScript:

```
$scope.columnBreak = 3; //Max number of colunms
$scope.startNewRow = function (index, count) {
    return ((index) % count) === 0;
};
```

Comment: it's not just a clear: left that i need, i actually need it to be in rows (wrapped in <div class="row"></div>

Comment: oh okay, sorry, i didn't know you need the rows to be in a separate div. 
Here, just in case you'd like to see a [js-bin](https://jsbin.com/cuneluvaba/edit?html,js,output) with my solution.